# How to resolve warning 'double *' differs in levels of indirection from 'double (*)[4][4]'

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I am trying to calculate eigenvalues of a matrix using a downloaded tqli algorithm. As a simple example I am trying to test it for a 4x4 identity matrix:

```
double ze[4][4];
double *zepointer;
ze[0][0] = 1;
ze[1][1] = 1;
ze[2][2] = 1;
ze[3][3] = 1;

ze[0][1] = 0;
ze[1][0] = 0;
ze[0][2] = 0;
ze[2][0] = 0;

ze[0][3] = 0;
ze[3][0] = 0;
ze[1][2] = 0;
ze[2][1] = 0;

ze[1][3] = 0;
ze[3][1] = 0;
ze[2][3] = 0;
ze[3][2] = 0;

zepointer = &ze;

tqli(de,ee,4,zepointer);
```

Besides that there is hopefully a smarter way to produce an identity matrix my compiler gives me a warning saying 'double *' differs in levels of indirection from 'double (*)[4][4]' for the line 'zepointer = &ze;'. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166833/differs-in-levels-of-indirection-from-int-c) and there it says the warning comes from referencing before declaring. However I can not see that I have done that in my code snippet.

TQLI is an algorithm to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I downloaded it from [here](http://cacs.usc.edu/education/phys516/src/TB/eigen.c).

Comment: Array indexes are *zero based*. So an array of four elements have indexes from `0` to `3` (inclusive).

Comment: As for your error (or rather how to solve it) what are you trying to do? What is `tqli`, what is its arguments, and what is `zepointer` supposed to actually point to?

Comment: Oh wow... Matlab really made me stupid. Could that be a source of the error though?

Comment: @Axel There should be so many duplicates for your question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: It all depends on how your `tqli` is defined, but most likely what you need is `double **zeropointer` instead of `double *zeropointer`

Comment: TQLI is a QL algorithm that calculates eigenvalues and eigenvector. The first input is the diagonal elements of the matrix, the second the subdiagonal elements and the last an identity matrix that in which columns the eigenvectors will be written.

Comment: @ChatterOne **No**. There's no way to get a `double**` from a `double[4][4]`. *Arrays are not pointers.*

Comment: I tried using double **zeropointer. It gave me the same error.

Comment: How is `tqli()`  declared?

Comment: As void tqli(double d[], double e[], int n, double **z)

Comment: @Axel, it appears that you are trying to obtain the address of the first element of the first row of your matrix, but until you show us how you intend to use it we can't really help you.  You could get that value with `zepointer = &ze[0][0]`, but that may not help.  If you want to do direct pointer arithmetic, you should not use a multi-dimensional array.  Pick one representation and stick with it.

Comment: Ok as shown there I made a double *zeptr; that is defined as zeptr = &ze[0][0]; With that there are no errors while building but during runtime the calculation crashes.

Comment: @Angew Where did I say that he should assign `ze` to `zeropointer`? I said that he needed a `double **` because *most likely* that's what the function was expecting. And indeed, it was.

Comment: So to summarize: When a function is declared as double **z it expects a pointer to the first element of a matrix using double *zeptr; zeptr = &ze[0][0];?

Comment: When a function expects `double**` you need to pass a `double**`. `&ze[0][0]` evaluates to a `double*` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to calculate eigenvalues of a matrix using a downloaded
>   tqli algorithm

There is no way to get a `double**` pointer by trying to cast `double[4][4]`.

You have to use different approach to supply required `double **` pointer for the `tqli` function.

You can pass your data using one of the method below.

First method:

1) Allocate memory for pointers to pointers `double **aa` and initialize them with pointers to row vectors in the `a` array.

Second method:

2) Allocate memory for pointers to matrix rows (as above). Allocate memory for the content of the rows. Copy all element values from your `ze`.

The testing program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define M_SIZE  4  // size of the nxn matrix

void tqli(double d[], double e[], int n, double **z)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
             double d = z[i][j]; 
             printf(" z[%i][%i] = %f \n", i, j, d );
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;

    double ze[M_SIZE][M_SIZE];
    double **zepointer;

    ze[0][0] = 1;
    ze[1][1] = 1;
    ze[2][2] = 1;
    ze[3][3] = 1;

    ze[0][1] = 0;
    ze[1][0] = 0;
    ze[0][2] = 0;
    ze[2][0] = 0;

    ze[0][3] = 0;
    ze[3][0] = 0;
    ze[1][2] = 0;
    ze[2][1] = 0;

    ze[1][3] = 0;
    ze[3][1] = 0;
    ze[2][3] = 0;
    ze[3][2] = 0;

    double de[M_SIZE] = {0};
    double ee[M_SIZE] = {0};

   // 1.---------------------

    printf(" First array is { {6,7,8,9}, {1,6,1,5}, {6,2,2,4}, {1,2,3,4} } \n"); 

    double a[M_SIZE][M_SIZE]={ {6,7,8,9}, {1,6,1,5}, {6,2,2,4}, {1,2,3,4} };

    double **aa = malloc( M_SIZE * sizeof(double*)); // allocate memory to hold the pointers to all rows

    for(i=0; i<M_SIZE; i++) 
        aa[i] = a[i];     // initialize pointers to the `a` rows

    tqli(de,ee,M_SIZE,aa); // test

    free(aa);              // free memory for row pointers


   // 2.--------------------

   printf(" Second array is { {1,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,1} } \n"); 

   zepointer = malloc( M_SIZE * sizeof(double*));    // allocate memory to hold the pointers to all rows

   // allocate memory for every row to hold column elements
   for(i=0; i<M_SIZE; i++) 
      zepointer[i] = malloc (M_SIZE * sizeof (double )) ;

   // assign values from your ze[][] matrix 
   for(i=0; i<M_SIZE; i++) 
      for(j=0; j<M_SIZE; j++)
            zepointer[i][j] = ze[i][j];

   tqli(de,ee,M_SIZE,zepointer); // test

   // cleanup

   for(i=0; i<M_SIZE; i++)       // free memory allocated for row elements 
     free(zepointer[i]) ;

   free(zepointer);              // free memory for the row pointers      

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 First method: array is { {6,7,8,9}, {1,6,1,5}, {6,2,2,4}, {1,2,3,4} } 
 z[0][0] = 6.000000 
 z[0][1] = 7.000000 
 z[0][2] = 8.000000 
 z[0][3] = 9.000000 

 z[1][0] = 1.000000 
 z[1][1] = 6.000000 
 z[1][2] = 1.000000 
 z[1][3] = 5.000000 

 z[2][0] = 6.000000 
 z[2][1] = 2.000000 
 z[2][2] = 2.000000 
 z[2][3] = 4.000000 

 z[3][0] = 1.000000 
 z[3][1] = 2.000000 
 z[3][2] = 3.000000 
 z[3][3] = 4.000000 

 Second method: array is { {1,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,1} } 
 z[0][0] = 1.000000 
 z[0][1] = 0.000000 
 z[0][2] = 0.000000 
 z[0][3] = 0.000000 

 z[1][0] = 0.000000 
 z[1][1] = 1.000000 
 z[1][2] = 0.000000 
 z[1][3] = 0.000000 

 z[2][0] = 0.000000 
 z[2][1] = 0.000000 
 z[2][2] = 1.000000 
 z[2][3] = 0.000000 

 z[3][0] = 0.000000 
 z[3][1] = 0.000000 
 z[3][2] = 0.000000 
 z[3][3] = 1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

From the function's  definition

```
void tqli(double d[], double e[], int n, double **z)
```

I conclude the function expects the 2 dimensions of  `double` being passed as a "jagged" aka "scattered" array.

To create such a thing go for the following:

```
const size_t rows = 4;
const size_t columns = 4;

/* Allocate as many pointers to column's 1st element as we have rows. */
double ** z = malloc(rows * sizeof *z);

/* Loop over all rows (pointers to column's 1st element). */
for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
  /* Allocate to each row (pointer to column's 1st element) as many doubles as we have columns. */
  z[r] = malloc(columns * sizeof *z[r]);
}


/* Assign value to z's elements. */
for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
  for (size_t c = 0; c < columns; ++c)
  {
    z[r][c] = r * c;
  }
}

tqli(..., z);

/* Free the stuff, 
   by calling free() on every item we received from malloc().  */
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
  free(z[i]);
}

free(z);
```

Adding sane error checking is left to the reader.